# phonegap run android fails with "...\classes.dex does not exist"

Tags: android, cordova, build

Just installed phonegap on windows 7 64bit and have run :

```
phonegap create testpg 
cd testpg 
phonegap -V run andoid
```

The last command aborts with the following error message:

```
[phonegap] detecting Android SDK environment... 
[phonegap] using the local environment 
[phonegap] compiling Android... 
[phonegap] Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android" 
[phonegap] Compiling app on platform "android" via command "cmd" /c D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\cordova\build 
[error] An error occurred while building the android project.Error executing "ant debug -f "D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\build.xml"": 
BUILD FAILED 
D:\Dev\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:962: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
D:\Dev\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:973: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
D:\Dev\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:313: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\bin\classes.dex does not exist
```

Does anyone knows what's going on and how i can fix this?

Thanks in advance!

PS. i tried and run "ant debug -f "D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\build.xml"":

and it gives quite verbose output. here is the last part :

```
...................... 
-dex: 
[dex] input: D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\bin\classes 
[dex] input: D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\classes.jar 
[dex] Pre-Dexing D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\CordovaLib\bin\classes.jar -> classes-529c048069aff9da86f06bdc712f5b33.jar 
[dex] Found Deleted Target File 
[dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\bin\classes.dex... 

-crunch: 
[crunch] Crunching PNG Files in source dir: D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\res 
[crunch] To destination dir: D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\bin\res 
[crunch] Crunched 0 PNG files to update cache 

-package-resources: 
[aapt] Creating full resource package... 
[aapt] Warning: AndroidManifest.xml already defines debuggable (in http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/an...); using existing value in 
manifest. 

-package: 
[apkbuilder] Current build type is different than previous build: forced apkbuilder run. 
[apkbuilder] Creating HelloWorld-debug-unaligned.apk and signing it with a debug key... 

BUILD FAILED 
D:\Dev\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:962: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
D:\Dev\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:973: The following error occurred while executing this line: 
D:\Dev\sdk\tools\ant\build.xml:313: com.android.sdklib.build.ApkCreationException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\bin\classes.dex does not exist 
....................
```

interestingly there is a line that says "[dex] Converting compiled files and external libraries into D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\bin\classes.dex..." and yet in the end build fails with "java.io.FileNotFoundException: D:\Dev\projects\testpg\platforms\android\bin\classes.dex does not exist"

Comment: try to run `%userprofile%\.cordova\lib\android\cordova\3.3.0\bin\check_reqs.bat` to see if it says "Looks like your environment fully supports cordova-android development!" or something else.

Answer (score 0):

Try rebuilding the project..
Go to Build > Make Project (ctrl + f9).
and run again
it worked for me..

Comment: Why? What changed?